# $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

$\alpha +\beta =\frac{3\pi}4$

$\sin(\alpha +\beta)= \frac{\sqrt{2}}2$

Why then $\cos(\alpha+\beta)= -\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$ if $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$

I keep getting answer on calculator sqrt(2)/2

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

I used latex equation to code converter. [Latex equation to code converter](https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php)

Comment: It does apply. $ $

Comment: I keep getting answer on calculator sqrt(2)/2 --> same as sin

Comment: (Writing $\theta$ for $\alpha+\beta$ ...) The fact that $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ does not guarantee that $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$. It could be that $\cos\theta=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$ ... which is what happens in the situation at hand, since $\theta=3\pi/4$ is a Second Quadrant angle.

Comment: I knew the rule, just thought that when it's sine or cosine(with no tan or ctg) that there is no sign change. Now looking at formulas and it's true. And it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Square both.
$$\sin^2(\alpha+\beta)=\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)^2=\frac24=\frac12$$
$$\cos^2(\alpha+\beta)=\left(\frac{-\sqrt2}2\right)^2=\frac24=\frac12$$
So the sum of squares is $1$ as required.